# How to query multiple namespaces using beam ReadFromDatastore

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My pipeline produces a Pcollection with unique_namespaces that I want to pass as a query parameter to ReadFromDatastore and then Flatten all the reads.

It looks like it is not possible to pass namespaces iterative list as a side input

```py
coll = (p 
| 'Reading from Datastore' >> ReadFromDatastore(project=PROJECT,query=query, 
   namespace=beam.pvalue.AsIter(unique_namespaces)
|'Flattening' >>  beam.Flatten() )
```

The approach that works is to save unique_namespaces PCollection as a csv file on storage, then open it and for each line do the following:

```
f = open('unique_namespaces.csv') 
unique_namespaces = csv.reader(f)
for namespace in unique_namespaces:
    label1 = 'Reading from Datastore: ' + namespace
    label2 = 'Flatting: ' + namespace
    read = p | label1 >> ReadFromDatastore(project=PROJECT,query=query, 
           namespace=namespace)
    merged = ((merged,read) | label2 >> beam.Flatten())
```

questions:

1) What is a more elegant way on reading from datastore on multiple namespaces?

2) How is it possible to provide a sideinput to ReadFromDatastore transform?

3) How to make python read the file from cloud storage AFTER it appears there from the beam writing to text transform?

Thank you!